# No Agreement found with Identities: 'AS2Identity'::'dummypartner1' and'AS2Identity'::'dummypartner2'

Tags: integration, azure-logic-apps

(Beginner)I am trying to create a new agreement and with 2 partners and for that I have followed the Microsoft [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-agreements) and kept them simple. I want to use a Logic App and in order to send the AS2 message using this agreement. When I trigger it always gives me error message of **No Agreement found with Identities: 'AS2Identity'::'dummypartner1' and'AS2Identity'::'dummypartner2'**. I have also attached the screenshots for better understanding.
Kindly guide me in this thanks.

Logic App error
[image]

Agreement and Partners
[image]
I want to use a Logic App and in order to send the AS2 message using agreement. When I trigger it always gives an error.